# Approximate 0 with a integer linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\alpha_i\in\mathbb{R}^m,i\in\{1,...,n\}$ linearly dependent over $\mathbb{R}$. Is it always possible to find Integers $t_1,...t_n, \exists j:t_j\neq0$, such that $\|\sum_{i=0}^{n} t_ia_i\|<\varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon>0$?

In words, this is the question if integer linear combinations of linearly dependent vectors can approximate 0 to any given accuracy. I am pretty sure this follows from the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, however I have been unable to prove it.

My general proof idea was following:
We find $\lambda_i$, with at least one nonequal to zero, such that
$$\sum\lambda_i\alpha_i=0$$(as the $\alpha_i$ are linearly dependent)

This way, we can find $\frac{a_i}{b_i}\in\mathbb{Q}$ that approximate the $\lambda_i$ sufficiently so that the sum does not differ from 0 too much. However, I am unable to construct these rationals to make this argument rigorous.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy over $\mathbb{R}$. Ill add that.

Comment: So far your argument to take a rational approximation arbitrarily close to $0$ seems good enough (by continuity), the only difficulty is going from rational numbers to integers without blowing up the error.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews the standard basis is not linearly dependent

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Yeah, misread depedent as independent. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem), given $\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_n$ real numbers and an integer number $N$, you can find integers $p_1,\ldots, p_n$ and $q$ with $1\leq q\leq N$ such that
$$|\lambda_i-p_i/q|\leq 1/qN^{1/n}$$
Therefore, if wlog $\|v_i\|\leq1$ for $i=1,\ldots, n$, then
$$\left\|\sum p_i v_i\right\|=q\left\|\sum p_iv_i/q\right\|=q\left\|\sum (\lambda_i-p_i/q)v_i\right\|\leq q n/qN^{1/n}=n/N^{1/n}\;.$$
Now, just take $N>1/(n\epsilon)^n$.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant to write the inequality. You are right, obviously.

Comment: Should that be $N>(n/\varepsilon)^n$?

Comment: And I would add that we also need $N>1/\max|\lambda_i|^n$ to guarantee that not all $p_i=0$.

Comment: Yes, n is at the numerator.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\sum \lambda_i a_i = 0$ with some $t_i$ not equal to zero. For any rational numers $q_i$ we have:

$||\sum q_i a_i|| = ||\sum \lambda_i a_i - \sum q_i a_i|| = ||\sum (\lambda_i - q_i) a_i || \leq \sum |\lambda_i - q_i| \cdot ||a_i|| \leq (\max ||a_i||) \sum |\lambda_i - q_i|$.

Now it's enough to find rational $q_i$ such that $\sum |\lambda_i - q_i| < \frac{\epsilon}{\max ||a_i||}$ which follows directly from the fact that $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: we’re looking for integers, not just rationals.

Comment: If you added the step from rationals->integers, that would be awesome. I know it works, but I can just not figure it out right now... I will keep trying nonetheless.